# Two string are not equal in c++

Tags: c++, string

I have a problem with comaparing two strings from std library on marked line of code. After this line output is "NO", although the strings after sort are the same with equal lenght. In sort I used bubble sort with swap function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

void sort(int n, std::string s);

int main() {
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2; 
 
    std::getline(std::cin, s1);
    std::getline(std::cin, s2);
 
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        std::cout << "NO";
    } else {
        sort(s1.length(), s1);
        sort(s2.length(), s2);     
        if (s1 == s2) { // <-- !
            std::cout << "YES";
        } else {
            std::cout << "NO";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
 
void sort(int n, std::string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (s[j] > s[j + 1]) {
                std::swap(s[j], s[j + 1]);
            }  
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `std::sort(s1.begin(), s1.end())` and `std::sort(s2.begin(), s2.end())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sort` function is not actually modifying the string `s1` being passed in. You need `s` to be a reference to the argument passed in:

```
void sort(int n, std::string &s);
```

and now changing `s` is the same as changing `s1`.

You need to change the signature in the function definition as well.

Also, you don't need to pass in the length of the string to the function, since a string already knows its own size:

```
void sort(std::string &s) {
   int n = s.length();
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The strings are passed by value. The copies are sorted but the originals are unchanged. A fix for your function is in the other answer. That will work.

An alternative approach is to use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead of your sort function. It uses iterators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

int main() {
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2; 
 
    std::getline(std::cin, s1);
    std::getline(std::cin, s2);
 
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        std::cout << "NO";
    } else {
        std::sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
        std::sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());     
        if (s1 == s2) { // <-- !
            std::cout << "YES";
        } else {
            std::cout << "NO";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could also modify your sort function to use iterators.